# Should I pass a PDO object to every object, or make a new one for each object?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I've done mostly procedural programming for years and am trying to wrap my head around OOP and PDO. I've started converting an application I've written to using classes instead of standalone functions (it's a nightmare, but I think it will be worth it..) and would like to use PDO instead of the regular `mysql_*` functions. I'm kind of flying by the seat of my pants, just learning as I go along, and I'm not sure how I should handle the PDO object(s).

I know it would be stupid to create a new PDO object every time I need to make a query, so that leaves two ways that I can see:

1. Creating a PDO object in each class (i.e. every time an object is created, call a member function to create a PDO for it to use).
2. Create PDO object at the beginning of my application and pass it to the constructor of every object that is created, and all the objects share the PDO object.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: You should certainly pass it, don't create it several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make more than one. You'll go crazy trying to manage all the DB connections.

One good solution would to make a [singleton object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for data access and retrieve it via it's static accessor method whenever you want to use the DB. That way you only ever have one place that manages DB access and PDOs. If you want to be a bit more [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) about it, you can put all SQL code in there too.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the application, you probably want to use a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to handle your database connection. Essentially, this will be a class that wraps your database connection and has a static function that will return your PDO object. However, because it's a Singleton it will only ever create one (assuming you don't make it more sophisticated). This saves you both from having to continuously make objects and from having to pass one object into all your objects, properly decoupling persistence from business logic.

Comment: What do you mean by, "Depending on the size of the application"? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Worrying about Singletons for particularly small applications with low load may be overkill. Likewise, larger applications might need some sort of pooling mechanism which may or may not be best served by a singleton. I'd need to know a lot more about your use case to be able to even start to advise on that front.